# How we can use ASP.NET Core Web API with JS fetch?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a simple authorization form. Currently I'm using JS fetch to send POST request to the server, but as response I get nothing, but sometimes it works (can't explain why).

If I use Postman, I can get response from the server, but if I use JS fetch, the server throws this strange exception (can't google it):

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HM4R02V04GJV", Request id "0HM4R02V04GJV:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.IO.IOException: The client reset the request stream.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()

[Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/028yz.png)

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZzTy.png)

As you can see - if I try do to this action few times - it works.

JS code:

```
function AuthRequest(){
let uname = document.querySelector('#username').value;
let pwd = document.querySelector('#pwd').value;

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({"Username":uname,"Password":pwd});

var requestOptions = {
    
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login([FromBody] LoginForm loginForm)
    {
        var user = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == loginForm.Username);

        var message = user == null ? "Can't find this user" : $"Found user {user.Username}";

        return message;
    }
```

**UPD:**

[Full request data from Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTXA3.png)

Startup.cs configuration

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHsts();
        
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire request being sent by your JavaScript client? You should be able to use your browser's developer tools and find it. I'd like to see all Headers being sent, not just the Content-Type that you specified. Also, is your JS method some kind of asynchronous function? I'm a bit rusty on my JS.

Comment: Sure. It's updated.

Comment: I think your issue has to do with the Fetch response stream closing early, which is noted in the Kestrel exception. Have you tried changing your controller action to return an IActionResult response instead of just a plain string? I think that may be causing some issues, since the IActionResult types are responsible for sending it as a whole HTTP response message instead of just the string data. I would change the controller return type to `Task<IActionResult>` rather than `ActionResult<string>`. Then `return Ok(message);`. The `Ok()` will send `message` in the body of a full response object.

Comment: Still have the same exception. Now it looks like: https://prnt.sc/vy8ahk
Maybe something is wrong with my server configuration? But still can't understand, why requests only from JS part causes this exception. Just tried another resource for testing (https://reqbin.com/) and it works perfect. But I still don't think it's JS fault.

Comment: And as mentioned above - sometimes it works. Just updated post with "Startup.cs' data
https://prnt.sc/vy8guz

Comment: If everything else is working except the JS request, that leads me to believe it's likely causing the issue. There's a few issues reported with Kestrel that produce this exception, although they were because of HTTP/2. Did you do any configuration for Kestrel in your API application? If so, your Startup class or anything else might be useful.

Comment: The solution for that was a lot easier. I had installed "Live Server" for my VS Code and problem was in <form onSumbit> that trying to force reload page. So when I click "Login" button - page reloads and cancels the request. Thank you for your advices. I'm still interested in case if someone will try to broke my server by that way. How could I prevent that?

Comment: @Elleyer, I assume you are using `<input type="submit">` tag to submit the form, if that is the case, try to use `<input type="button">` tag, then, in this button click event, you could prevent the default event using the `Event.preventDefault()`, after that call the API using JS fetch.

Comment: @Elleyer Thank you very much! I was having similar trouble trying to log user browser information on page exit